# Find the order of cyclic group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> > Let $G$ be a cyclic group generated by $a$ satisfy the property that there exist $n \in \mathbb N$ such that  $n=$ min$\{|i-j| : i\neq j \in \mathbb N,$  $a^i = a^j \}$. Then the order of $G$ is $n$.

Clearly $a, a^2, a^3, \cdots, a^n$ are all distict elements and there  exist $r \in \mathbb N$ such that $a^{n+r} = a^r$. I want to show that $a^{n+1} = a$. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Note that from $a^{n+r} = a^r$ you immediately find that $a^n = 1$.

Comment: Elements of $G$ of the form $a^i$, where $i \in \mathbb N$, so the identity element of $G$ is of the form $a^t$, we need to show that $t =n$

Comment: Indeed, the smallest positive $t$ such that $a^t = 1$ will be $n$. You already showed that $a, a^2, \ldots a^n$ are distinct so none of $a^i$, $i \lt n$ can be the identity (otherwise $a^{i+1} = a^i$). Moreover from what you found, $a^{n + r} = a^r$, simply use that $a^{n + r} = a^na^r$.

Comment: I have found $r$ by the definition of $n =$ min $\{ |i-j| : \; i\neq j \in \mathbb N, a^i = a^j$, but i did not not mentioned that $r =1$. I am agree with you  
 none of $a^i, \; i < n$ can be identity.